# mysql 8.0 fai to start after add lower_case_table_names=2 in config file

Tags: mysql

I have installed mysql server (version : 8.0) into a Linux server.

MySQL database is CASE SENSITIVE in  Linux environment.

I add " lower_case_table_names=2 " under `[mysqld]` , and i restart the server using `systemctl restart mysqld.service` , But Mysql fail to start

This is my `my.cnf` configuration

```
[mysqld]
#
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M
#
# Remove the leading "# " to disable binary logging
# Binary logging captures changes between backups and is enabled by
# default. It's default setting is log_bin=binlog
# disable_log_bin
#
# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
lower_case_table_names=1
bind-address=192.168.1.25
# Remove leading # to revert to previous value for default_authentication_plugin,
# this will increase compatibility with older clients. For background, see:
# https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin
# default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

and this is the log file `/var/log/mysqld.log`

```
2019-02-22T08:50:44.849482Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 6819
2019-02-22T08:50:45.112952Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('1') and data dictionary ('0').
```

How i can resolv this issues

Thank YOU

Answer (score 1):

```
Table and database names are stored on disk using the lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement, but MySQL converts them to lowercase on lookup. Name comparisons are not case sensitive. This works only on file systems that are not case-sensitive! InnoDB table names and view names are stored in lowercase, as for lower_case_table_names=1.
```

Please look at the second sentence since you switch this from 1 to 2 .. You are on Linux so case-sensitive this would work only on Windows not in your case. Also if you put it on windows you have to backup, convert table and view names in lowercase.

More to read here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: the only fix is to migrate to Windows ?

Comment: For the option 2 as the documentation says 'This works only on file systems that are not case-sensitive!' which is only Windows :) On linux will not work